# Whats the difference between IP's from DigitalOcean and IP's from Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, virtual-machine, digital-ocean

I've got some questions about ip's from Digital Ocean and Google Cloud, I have little knowledge about IP's and networks, i have two apps, one is running on a DigitalOcean server (dropplet) and the other is running on a VM Instance of Google Cloud, i was trying to setup code-server on each server.

In the droplet of DigitalOcean I configure successfully code-server, when i was running the command `code-server` code server got online on the address: `http://127.0.0.1:8080` so i couldn't get into the app 'cause it was the local IP of the droplet, so i couldn't write that IP on my browser for obvious reasons, doing a little research i found the flag `--bind-addr` for code-sever, then i tried this command: `code-server --bind-addr=192.231.24.04:8080` (That IP is an IP example) and it works, i was able to access code server writing in my navigator `http://192.231.24.04:8080` and also i can access with `mydomain.com:8080`

In Google Cloud i tried to do the same, but i couldn't, i configured succesfully code-server on the VM Instance, when i run `code-server` code server got online on the address: `http://127.0.0.1:8080` (As in DigitalOcean) obviously, that's the local IP
of the VM Instance, then i proceeded to do the same thing that i did in DigitalOcean, use the `---bind-addr` flag, so i wrote this on the console: `code-server --bind-addr=104.652.18.64:8080` (That IP is an IP example) and the console put this: `error listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 104.652.18.64:8080`, I thought Google Cloud was blocking the port 8080, so i unlock it, but still wasn't working, doing a little research i found that i had to use the IP `0.0.0.0:8080`, so i wrote this command: `code-server --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:8080` and i tried to access on my browsing using `http://104.652.18.64:8080` and it works... i don't know why, i also tried using `myseconddomain.com:8080` and also works

So i don't know what's the difference, What does IP 0.0.0.0 mean?

I returned to DigitalOcean droplet and i tried to do the same, i wrote: `code-server --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:8080` and in the digital ocean droplet says: `error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:8080`

So... what's the difference?

Why does DigitalOcean work in a way that Google Cloud does not work and Google Cloud works in a way that DigitalOcean does not work?

I appreciate your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud's networking has a distinction between [internal and external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses).  In particular, a GCE VM won't actually have an interface with the externally visible IP address.  Instead, Google Cloud Networking will transparently route from the external IP address to the internal IP address, assuming such routing is allowed by the firewall  for that port.  Thus, when you tried to start code-server listening to the external IP address specifically, the VM didn't know what that was referring to, as the interface did not exist inside the VM.

Generally on a host (in the context of starting a service on a given interface), 0.0.0.0 [refers to any/all of the IP addresses on the machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0#As_a_host_address).  In your case, it means that you have started code-server listening to the internal IP address, and since you have removed the 8080 block in the GCP firewall, GCP networking will route requests to the external address to the VM.

I am not certain about DigitalOcean, but I presume that they do not have a different internal and external IP address, and thus when you start code-server listening to the external IP address directly, it attaches to the correct address.  The error you are getting when trying 0.0.0.0 indicates something else is already listening on port 8080.  Check that you stopped all the prior code-server process first, as well as anything else that may be listening on 8080 on any IP already.